# How do you select multiple objects based on certain criteria with MongoEngine?

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, mongoengine, django-queryset

I am building a Python Flask web app using MongoDB and MongoEngine. I am trying to select multiple objects based on certain criteria. When I try `Item.objects.get(field="criteria")` it throws a `MultipleObjectsReturned` error which is what it should return based on the documentation (https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet). I know that it should return multiple objects. What query can I use to return multiple objects based on certain criteria?

Edit: I tried Item.objects.filter(field="criteria") and forgot to change one of the calls on the page so it was still returning `MultipleObjectsReturned`. After seeing the answers I noticed the bug and now it works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
Item.objects.filter(field="criteria")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Item.objects(field="criteria")
```

or

```
Item.objects.filter(field="criteria")
```